# Async set/get variable in class will not work

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have async code that works as follows:

```py
RUNNING=False

def is_running():
    global RUNNING
    return RUNNING

def my_stop_func():
    global RUNNING
    RUNNING = False


def start_threads():
    # code here that starts a number of threads
    # one of them can stop this service and calls my_stop_func()
    global RUNNING
    RUNNING = True

def join_threads():
    # Code that joins all created threads
    pass

def main():
    # init code etc...
    start_threads()

    while is_running():
        pass
    join_threads()
```

However doing the very small change below will not work.

```py
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False
HI = None

def is_running():
    global HI
    return HI.running

def my_stop_func():
    global HI
    HI.running = False


def start_threads():
    # code here that starts a number of threads
    # one of them can stop this service and calls my_stop_func()
    global HI
    HI = Hello()
    HI.running = True
```

Of course I'm doing it wrong, but I just haven't found a solution that works even if I add async keywords with locks etc.
Any hints?

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects

Comment: There is no async function here. The text talks about threads (which is not the same as async), but there are no threads in the code either. Also, it is not said what "does not work". I would suggest to create a [mcve] and state the problem clearly.

Comment: @zvone async no, standard threading - he tries to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing appears more to be `logical error`, rather than an issue with `threading` or `async programming` - in your original code you're using variable `RUNNING`, that way you're able to control the state of the threads, and now, in the class-based approach you've correctly encapsulated the state within an instance of the `Hello` class (`HI`), but there's inconsistency in your `my_stop_func` function/method; In your original code, you set `RUNNING = false` which is indicator that thread should stop, and then in the class based approach you mistakenly set `HI.running = True` in `my_stop_func`, where it applies that the threads should keep running.

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False

HI = None

def is_running():
    global HI
    return HI.running

def my_stop_func():
    global HI
    HI.running = False  # Corrected from True to False

def start_threads():
    # code here that starts a number of threads
    # one of them can stop this service and calls my_stop_func()
    global HI
    HI = Hello()
    HI.running = True

def main():
    # init code etc...
    start_threads()

    while is_running():
        pass  # Implement your thread monitoring or other logic here
```

As for async and locks, in case your threads are accessing shared resources or need to be synced, then using locks might be needed, but from provided code I suspect main concern is just to control the running state of the threads; therefore if you're facing race conditions or other concurrency issues, you might need to implement locking mechanisms or use other sync primitives.

**UPDATE 1:**
As OP stated that issue with `my_stop_func` was just a typo and the rest of his code is class-based approach is as intended, there could be potential issues:

1. Initialization of `HI`: You have to ensure that `HI` is initialized before any thread actually try to access its `running` attribute, that's the most common issue if threads start running before `HI` is set to an instance of `Hello`;
2. There could be potential problem with threading and object visibility, where in these kind of environments, changes that are made to an object in one thread might not be visible immediately to other threads, but again, because of `GIL` it's less likely, but still should be considered.
3. Race conditions: in case where multiple threads are doing R/W operation to `HI.running` without sync, you might run into race conditions -> solving these would be by using threading locks.
4. The code that OP showed is using standard threading, not async programming, the `async` keyword and locks are more relevant in an `asyncio`-based programming, so in case you want to do this you can introduce a lock in the `Hello` class, then sync access to the running variable.

```
import threading

class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

HI = None

def is_running():
    global HI
    with HI.lock:
        return HI.running

def my_stop_func():
    global HI
    with HI.lock:
        HI.running = False

def start_threads():
    global HI
    HI = Hello()
    with HI.lock:
        HI.running = True

def main():
    # init code etc...
    start_threads()

    while is_running():
        pass  # Implement your thread monitoring or other logic here

# main()  # Uncomment to run the main function
```

In the modifications, I've added a lock to ensure that access to `HI.running` is thread-safe, and you'd use with `HI.lock:` whenever its required for you to read/write to `HI.running` - this way you ensure that the check and the update of the running state are atomic operations from the perspective of your threads

Comment: That was a typo from re-writing my code. The code in the program I have it's set to False as you specify. Thanks for the comment though. But I still cannot set this variable to False, or the ```is_running()``` always returns True

Comment: @DecafSux I just updated my answer, so have a look at it again.

Comment: Thanks I read your comments, made some changes and now it works. It had to do with a "async" keyword at the wrong place in the original code. Attributing you the credit since it made me look in the right direction. Sorry for the fuzz and thanks for the help!